# OK and Cancel Button in Action bar for Android

Tags: android-layout, android-actionbar

I want to design like this below:

[image]

`OK` button in left side and `cancel` button in right side and in middle, the name of activity, and below tabs are already created.

Comment: What have you tried, what code works and what doesn't? There are literally a million ways to do this.

Comment: Don't know any way to do this...

Comment: What do you have thus far? codewise

Answer (score 0):

Got Solution.

- Create a custom view for action bar
- write this code in your activity

  ```
          actionBar = getActionBar();
          actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
          actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
          LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
          View mView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_actionbar,null);
          actionBar.setCustomView(mView);
          actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
          mView.findViewById(R.id.btncancel).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {
                  Toast.makeText(VehicleActivity.this, "Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
          });

          mView.findViewById(R.id.btndone).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {
                  Toast.makeText(VehicleActivity.this, "DONE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
          });
  ```